# PowerPivot is not pulling all the records from Tabular Model

Tags: powerpivot, ssas-tabular

I have been facing an issue with many PowerPivot models. The Tabular Model is the source for my PowerPivot model and I have around 1.2 million records in my Tabular model. Every time the Tabular Model is successfully refreshed and processed.  I'm trying to refresh my PowerPivot assuming it will be refreshed with the same number of records from Tabular model. But it's never getting loaded with the whole data and loading only 700,000 records with a status of 'Successfully Refreshed'.

Since both Tabular Models and PowerPivot models are In-memory, I'm always closing the other Tabular models and PowerPivot models when I'm refreshing a particular tabular/PowerPivot model. But I'm never getting my PowerPivot completely refreshed with that of the source Tabular model.

It's quite irritating. Can you guys suggest any solutions please?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why are you using a Tabular model as a source for Power Pivot? Anything that uses Power Pivot as a back-end can use Tabular as a back-end. They are the same engine. By doing so, you lose pretty much all the benefits of running Tabular on a server and may as well just hit the source you use in the Tabular model directly from the Power Pivot model.

Comment: What version of Excel (build number and all) and what version of SSAS (with build number)? I have a vague recollection this was a bug that has subsequently fixed so try making sure you update to latest versions and retest.